# Query parent objects and filter child lists without excluding parents

Tags: python, join, select, sqlalchemy, orm

I managed to query a list of `Parent` objects while at the same time filter each parent's list of children using `contains_eager()`

```
stmt = select(Parent)
stmt = stmt.outerjoin(Parent.child)
stmt = stmt.filter(Child.a == None)
stmt = stmt.options(contains_eager(DbStudy.milestones))
parents = session.scalars(stmt).unique().all()
```

For each `Parent` in my `parents` result set, the list of children is filtered by `a == None` which is what I want.

However, the `parents` result set does only contain `Parents` where at least one child with `a == None` exists.

What I want to achieve is that `parents` are not filtered at all. If none of the parent's children meets the condition, I still want the `Parent` to be in the result set with an empty list of children.

Is this possible with `contains_eager()`. Are there alternative approaches like `subquery()`? (I tried that but couldn't get it to work)

Comment: You should be doing the sqlalchemy equivalent of OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Not sure what you mean or what I need to change exactly. I'm using outerjoin already in my statement above and according to the docs, contains_eager is the way to go to filter child lists:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result